# Apache2 still shows a list of files instead of my webpage ( Directoryindex adjusted )

Tags: apache, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, webserver

I've recently launched ubuntu instance at AWS, with LAMP & Ajenti.
Uploaded my files to var/www section, checked out Directoryidex ( index.html is present). But when I try to access my web page it gives me a list of files instead of running a page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that both `DocumentRoot` and `DirectoryIndex` are set correctly in `VirtualHosts` and/or `.htaccess`. Also, you might want **not** anyone to see your file tree, use the following snippet to avoid that.

```
<Directory /path/to/your/dir>
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure index.html exists at the web root. When you see the list of files in your browser, make sure index.html exists. (Sorry can't post as comment, not enough rep)